# Using Mailjet API in Grails application for sending mails

Tags: java, email, grails, configuration, mailjet

I want to integrate [Mailjet API](https://www.mailjet.com/) in Grails application for sending mails, I have already used ASYNC mail API for sending mail in grails, in this api , I need to give configuration parameters in config.groovy. Now as I am using Mailjet for sending mails, so I need to give Mailjet SMTP settings in config.groovy, so I give as follows :

```
grails {
       mail {
         host = "in.mailjet.com"
         port = 465
         username = "xxx@gmail.com"
         password = "xxx"
         props = ["mail.smtp.host": "in.mailjet.com",
                  "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port": "465",
                  "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class": "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                  "mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
                  "mail.smtp.port": "465",
                  "mail.smtp.user": "API key of mailjet",
                  "mail.smtp.password": "secret key of mailjet"]
       }
    }
```

Here is the example of sending mail using [java code](https://www.mailjet.com/docs/code/java)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

username and password have to contain your api key and the api secret, not the credentials
that you use to log into the web site.
Using mail.smtp.host as a property is redundant and should not be necessary.

Comment: Setting the username and password as instructed above should work. You should also remove the last two lines which seems to overwrite the username and password.